# What is PSNormalizer / normalizerd process

Tags: macos

I am running MacOS 10.14.6 on an iMac, and have found that there is a process called normalizerd that is doing about 2TB of disk writes per day. 
[image]
Through some internet search, found that there is a system called com.apple.print.normalizerd, which appears to be initiated by an XPC(?) called PSNormalizer. I think this might be a background process, possibly connected to pdf/postscript, and installed by XCode.

A grep for PSNormalizer in /Library found entries like

`Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PSNormalizer.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries/libICC.tbd:install-name:    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PSNormalizer.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libICC.dylib`

> Overall, I would love to know in more detail what this process is, and more importantly how to make it stop! Thanks a lot for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I now know what was causing this. I attempted to print to a Kyocera photocopier that doubles as a fax machine. This process seems to have been going around and around, attempting and re-attempting to create documents in a suitable format for faxing. I found the (unprinted) documents in a lingering unseen print queue. Having removed the documents, the uncontrolled disk writing has ceased.

Answer (score 1):

The PSNormalizer framework is (was) part of the OS responsible for interpreting PostScript language into displayed graphics and text.

It has now been removed from the OS in Sonoma (macOS 14).

In this context, it's likely that the print drivers were calling it to convert PS into whatever format the FAX protocol uses.